# Understanding different NFC tag-technologies

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, ndef, iso-15693

I am trying to understand how to handle different tag technologies.
Until now I wrote/read my tags using NDEF messages. Now I want to read/write NfcV tags.

Reading different tutorials I found out, that I need to use the `transceive(byte[])` method of an NfcV object.

Trying to work with NfcV I faced very random and wrong behavior. Data was not sent, saved into wrong blocks or only partially saved, while mixing up with previous data. NDEF message saving always overwrote the previous data.

Am I just going the wrong way, can i use NdefMessage/NdefRecord on NfcV tags?

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to communicate (e.g. read or write) with the tag using tag specific commands through the `transceive()`-method or if you want to store NDEF messages on the tag (i.e. use the tag as Type V NDEF tag platform)?

Comment: I want to read/write data from/to a tag. Thats all... best would be "easiest way"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use Android's `Ndef`/`NdefFormatable` tag technologies if the operating system supports the Type V NDEF tag platform specification for that tag. Particularly with Android versions prior to 4.2, there is only limited support for NDEF on NfcV (ISO 15693) tags.

If Android does not list `Ndef`/`NdefFormatable` for your tag, you will have to stick to using the tag's specific command set with the `NfcV.transceive()`-method.

Comment: Im using multiple different Tag... having a few of them not allowing Ndef it looks like i have to go with `NfcV.transceive()` :(... I'm already having my problems with that....

Comment: @TorhanBartel Any specific reason for the un-accept?

Comment: Tried to delete the question itself